# Bootstrap 4 ordering columns on mobile/desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a responsive layout for a ecommerce productdetailpage. I would like to order the columns different on mobile without getting white spaces. This is what it looks like currently:

[image: current format]

The problem is on desktop when for example there is not content for box 3. There will be a huge white gap above box 5. So box 5 has to move under box 2. Like this:

[image: Desired format]

I don't know if this is even possible through using framework Bootstrap 4, if not I'm looking forward to see how you would doing this without. Hopefully someone can help me out.

For the structure i use the following bootstrap grid:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it is possible through using framework Bootstrap 4 like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sf071c6m/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to know what layout should be applied, e.g. though JavaScript. Then when we will know what layout should be used, we can apply our layout.

So we car create a div and divide this div into two parts. Then using `flex-grow` property, we can fill the remaining space:

```css
html,body{height:100%;}

.bg-purple {
  background: rgb(48,0,50);
}
.bg-gray {
  background: rgb(74,74,74);
}
.bg-blue {
  background: rgb(50,101,196);
}
.bg-red {
  background: rgb(196,50,53);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-6 bg-red">
      <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple flex-grow-1">
          <div class="text-white">
            <div>1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-blue flex-grow-1">
          <div class="text-white">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-6 bg-gray">
        <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-info" style="height: 30px;">
          <div class="text-white">
            <div>Column with fixed height 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-success flex-grow-1">
          <div class="text-white">Fille the remaining space 5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>      
    
  </div>
</div>
```

[An example at jsfiddle can be seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/0qzra14c/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfect for desktop. But now i would like to change the order of the columns on mobile as on the first picture on the right. E.g. 1-2-3-4-5.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">50%</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">50%</div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33.33%</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:orange;">33.33%</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">33.33%</div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- Or let Bootstrap automatically handle the layout -->

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please alwas add a suffient explanation of your solution. An unexplained code-snippet is low-quality.